# Upgrade from cordova-1.8.1 to cordova-2.0.0 failed to iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I upgrade my PhoneGap (or better Cordova) project from 1.8.1 version to 2.0.0.
The operation is completed succesfully in Android and WindowsPhone7 project.
I have issue in iOS project:
When I build project to try the functionality, the output console alerts this:

```
2012-08-19 11:02:17.480 MyProjectName[1414:13703] Error: executing module function 'setInfo' in module 'cordova/plugin/ios/device'. Have you included the iOS version of the cordova-1.8.1.js file?
2012-08-19 11:02:17.689 MyProjectName[1414:13703] CDVPlugin class CDVDevice (pluginName: Device) does not exist.
2012-08-19 11:02:17.703 MyProjectName[1414:13703] ERROR: Plugin 'Device' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in Cordova.plist.
2012-08-19 11:02:17.720 MyProjectName[1414:13703] FAILED pluginJSON = {"className":"Device","methodName":"getDeviceInfo","arguments":["Device1"]}
```

The first row above indicates that Cordova find the old JS file, and not the newest 2.0.0.

How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks to all.

Comment: Same issue here after upgrading from Cordova 1.6.1 to 2.0.0 for iOS. Not sure if it's actually blocking anything in my app.

Comment: Make sure you follow _all_ the steps from the upgrade guide here http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_upgrading_ios_index.md.html#Upgrading%20Cordova%20iOS

Answer (score 1):

I made sure I had added the following entry to my plist file :

```
Key: Device 
Type: String 
Value: CDVDevice
```

But I kept getting the same message in the logs, even after adding the above.

So I cleaned my Xcode project and that fixed it for me:

```
Product -> Clean
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a new entry under Plugins in your Cordova.plist file (under the Supporting Files group) - the key is "Device" and the value is "CDVDevice"

Comment: I already added the new entry. It is the first row in Plugins section. Maybe, do it must to be the last children?

Comment: order does not matter in this case